# Sling deploy content and bundle with maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sling, sightly, sling-models

Iam searching for a maven based solution to deploy apache sling bundle and content (including jsp/html, etc files) on my sling standalone server.

I stated this private project to learn about sightly and sling models without using AEM. It is my first only sling project.

Ive created a sling bundle and a sling content project from the specific archetypes. Ive stated working with the Eclipse Sling IDE tools, but iam used to IntelliJ and there is no plugin to deploy the contetent the same way. I think its possible to build and deploy a package with both (bundle and content) by using maven.

Hopefully someone of you have some instructions or ideas to solve this problem and make it more comfortable developing web projects with apache sling.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `maven-sling-plugin` can install bundles in a Sling instance, and bundles can include initial content which is installed when they become active.

The `slingbucks` sample demonstrates this, if you build it as shown below it will be installed in the Sling instance running on port 8080 and its initial content (defined under `src/main/resources/SLING-CONTENT` as specified in that module's `pom.xml`) will be installed:

```
mvn clean install org.apache.sling:maven-sling-plugin:install -Dsling.url=http://localhost:8080/system/console
```

If you use the Sling parent pom you can also use the `autoInstallBundle` profile to do the same thing using the default URL that that pom defines:

```
mvn clean install -P autoInstallBundle
```

Answer (score 1):

This project may help you https://github.com/auniverseaway/slick, see the pom.xml file there

Comment: Very cool thank you i will give it a try. I see you are using sling models and sightly as well maybe i can get some more help from your project

Comment: Glad it helps but this is not my code, the best answer is what Bertrand Delacretaz said, it's part of the sling-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

`<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Sling-Initial-Content>
                jcr_root/content;
                    overwriteProperties:=false;
                    overwrite:=false;
                    uninstall:=false;
                    path:=/content;
                    maven:mount:=false,
                jcr_root/apps/slick;
                    overwrite:=true;
                    path:=/apps/slick;
                    maven:mount:=false,
                jcr_root/apps/sling;
                    overwrite:=true;
                    path:=/apps/sling;
                    maven:mount:=false,
                jcr_root/etc;
                    path:=/etc;
                    overwriteProperties:=false;
                    uninstall:=false,
                jcr_root/i18n;
                    path:=/etc/i18n/net.zum.slick;
                    overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true
            </Sling-Initial-Content>
            <Bundle-Activator>net.zum.slick.internal.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Sling-Model-Packages>
              net.zum.slick
            </Sling-Model-Packages>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`

All in all the files inside the directories defined in  `<Sling-Initial-Content>` space  of the `maven-bundle-plugin` will be deployed with the bundle, correct?